# How to make header - content - footer layout in android with footer stick at bottom

Tags: android, xml

This is my activity layout content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="wrapper"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
 >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="header"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="50">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent "
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Header"
            android:textSize="40dp" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="main-content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        >
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Content" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="footer"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"

        >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Footer"
            android:textSize="40dp" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

The footer is already stick to the bottom, but the content is stick to the top instead of after the "header". I thought about use "Linear Layout" but it's don't have **android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"**. What must I do?

Answer (score 0):

Just align the layout of header to parent top.
then align the main content below of your header.

Let me edit for you but I will let you to test it..

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="wrapper"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="header"
        android:id="@+id/rl_header"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="50"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent "
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Header"
            android:textSize="40dp" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="main-content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/rl_header">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Content" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="footer"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"

        >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Footer"
            android:textSize="40dp" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```